# PostgreSQL copy to with encoding using psycopg2

Tags: pandas, postgresql, encoding, psycopg2

I am fetching data from remote database and trying to write it with UTF8 encoding as CSV file.
This is what I have now:

```
query = "select * from hotels limit 50000"
output_query = "copy ({0}) to stdout with csv header ecnoding 'UTF8'".format(query)
filename = "hotels.csv"

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    cur.copy_expert(output_query, f)
```

But this usually throws:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u016f' in position 52: character maps to <undefined>
```

If i change query limit to lets say 1000 mentioned exception does not occur, but if i try to load generated csv file using pandas, following exception occurs:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem? How to export sql table to csv the proper way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have added `encoding='utf-8'` in open function.

Comment: It's good practice to always set the encoding in your `open()` commands. There's a Semgrep rule for this if you use CI, that can catch it.